# Plotting error using the ppp function

Tags: r, plot, geospatial, spatstat

I am plotting the location of oil refineries in Houston, TX. I defined the study area with the following code.

```
 P4S.latlon <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 ")
 county.lines <-readShapePoly("tl_2017_us_county/tl_2017_us_county.shp", verbose = T, proj4string = P4S.latlon)

 harris <- subset(county.lines, county.lines$GEOID == 48201)
 brazoria <- subset(county.lines, county.lines$GEOID == 48039)
 galveston <- subset(county.lines, county.lines$GEOID == 48167)
 chambers <- subset(county.lines, county.lines$GEOID == 48071)
 liberty <- subset(county.lines, county.lines$GEOID == 48291)
 all.counties <- rbind(harris, brazoria, galveston, chambers, liberty)

 ShapePoly <- as(all.counties, "SpatialPolygons")
 study.area <- as(ShapePoly, "owin")
```

Plotting the study area works as intended.

To plot the refinery data I used the following code

```
refinery <- data.frame(refinery)
attach(refinery)
refinery <- ppp(coords.x1, coords.x2, window = study.area)
```

The refinery data was originally a shapefile. I converted it to a data frame so I could use ppp().

The issue arising is when I plot refinery there are no points, only shape files.

```
plot(refinery, pch = 20, col = "firebrick1")
```

[image: This is the resulting plot]

I am writing this script for a class project and usually use ArcGIS for my spatial projects. I'm not sure what could be causing this as I have done extensive research on the ppp function and have replicated this code with a different data set. I would like to have the refineries plotted as points against the county shapefiles.

Comment: `ppp` uses lon-lat not lat-lon   What happens if you switch x1 and x2?

Comment: @G5W my points were entered with lon-lat. I did try switching x1 and x2 but no points were able to be plotted in the study area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say for sure since you didn't provide a reproducible example (no link to download data, no loading of R packages used, etc.), but I think this is simply due to the colouring: The argument `col` controls the colour of the study region (window). To plot the points a given colour use `cols`, e.g. `cols = "firebrick1"`.

**NOTE:** You are working directly in lon, lat so your points are really on a sphere (ellipsoid), and very little analysis in R can be done directly for these coordinates (even the plotting is slightly wrong since 1 deg long is different than 1 deg lat). If you continue your analysis you really need to project your coordinates to flat space (use e.g. `sf::st_transform()` or `sp::spTransform()`).

Answer (score 1):

When you plot an object of class `ppp`, the function `plot.ppp` is executed. The help file for `plot.ppp` explains that the colours of the points are controlled by the argument `cols`.